# db instruction it is executed after call

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, shellcode

I am learning to program in assembly language and I found this code that I can not understand how an instruction is executed

```
xor eax,eax
xor ebx,ebx
xor ecx,ecx
xor edx,edx
jmp short string
code:
pop ecx 
mov bl,1
mov dl,13
mov al,4
int 0x80
dec bl
mov al,1
int 0x80
string: 
call code 
db 'hello, world!'
```

After the call to code, why the db instruction it is executed? if a call instruction it is executed before

Comment: There's no `db` "instruction". `db` is a directive to the assembler that tells it to place one or more bytes into your binary (i.e. your executable / object file).

Comment: Why do you think it will be executed? The `call` will redirect CPU to address `code`.. from there there's no redirection back to the code after the `call`. (hint: the `call` is used to store the address of the string to the top of the stack, not to "call subroutine")

Comment: Why did the directive run? Not supposed should go to code after call

Comment: I don't get you, the `'hello..'` bytes are not executed.

Comment: The directive "ran" when you assembled the program, not when you executed the program. Anyway, if your question is _"how could the string be printed"_, the answer is _"you told the OS to do so by using system call 4"_.

Comment: And since you say _"I am learning to program in assembly language"_ you should stay away from obfuscated code like this. Find a better book/tutorial that's aimed at beginners.

Comment: Can you please check listing file after assembling this? To see how the machine code looks. The `db` is just other way how to define bytes. If somebody would want to have fun, he could have try to find a way how to produce memory content `'hello..'` by instructions, for example "hello" can be done also by `push   0x6f6c6c65` instruction. (NOT executing it.. but assembling it)  It also works the other way. You can use `db` to define actual instructions (it just doesn't make sense, as you can write instructions directly in assembly, so using `db` would be just obfuscation for source reader).

Comment: what I find strange is that it goes to code and stores in the stack the value of the string too

Comment: `call` stores the return address on the stack, which in this case happens to be the address of the string `'hello, world!'`. That address is then popped into `ecx` (which is the string pointer argument for system call 4). Like I said in my previous comment, this is obfuscated code and it makes no sense for a beginner to try to learn from code like this.

Comment: For CPU there is no "code" or "data", just memory and it's content ([machine code](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/assembly/1358/getting-started-with-assembly-language/8901/machine-code#t=201702170830054427132)). Any content in memory is both data (when read) and code (when executed). The code you presented is just using instructions of CPU in a non-beginner way to achieve what the programmer want. You should load that code in the debugger, and go slowly instruction by instruction over it, checking it against instruction reference guide with details how instructions work.

Comment: Are you aware the tutorial you are using for assembler is for shellcode and exploits? If you aren't writing shellcode and doing exploits then a different tutorial might be better. If you aren't doing shellcode then my new tag should be removed from the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to point out what I meant by "other way defining byte values", this variant of your code will do the same thing, but it shows how to define string by instructions, and how to define instructions by `db` directive ... both makes the source harder to read for human, but for the Assembler the difference is negligible, it will produce the same binary machine code, and for CPU the same machine code is the same machine code, it does not care how your source did look.

I also tried to extensively comment each line, what it does, and why it is used in the code.

Also the code is written in this non-trivial way, because it is example of shell-exploit payload, where your assembly must not only do what you want, but its resulting machine code must also conform to additional constraints, like it can't contain any zero (makes it difficult to pass it around as "string" during injecting the payload code with some exploit), it must be PIC (position-independent code), and it can't use any absolute address, or assume any particular position while being executed, etc.

```
    ; sets basic registers eax,ebx,ecx,edx to zero (ecx not needed BTW)
    xor eax,eax
    db '1', 0xDB        ; xor ebx,ebx defined by "db" for fun
    db '1', 0xC9        ; xor ecx,ecx defined by "db" for fun
    xor edx,edx
    ; short-jump forward to make later "call code" to produce
    ; negative relative offset, so zero in "call" opcode is avoided
    ; "call code" from here would need zeroes in rel32 offset encoding
    jmp short string    ; the "jmp short string" is encoded as "EB 0F"
code:
    pop ecx             ; loads the address of string from the stack into ecx
    mov bl,1            ; ebx = 1 = STD_OUT stream, avoiding zeroes in
        ; "mov ebx,1" opcode, so instead "xor ebx,ebx mov bl,1" is used
    mov dl,13           ; edx = 13 = length of string
    mov al,4            ; eax = 4 = sys_write
    int 0x80            ; sys_write(STD_OUT, 'hello, world!', 13);
    dec bl              ; ebx = 0 = exit code "OK"
    mov al,1            ; eax = 1 = sys_exit
    int 0x80            ; sys_exit(0);
string:
    call code           ; return address == string address -> pushed on stack
    ; also "code:" is ahead, so relative offset is negative => no zero in opcode
    ; resulting call opcode is "E8 EC FF FF FF"

    ; following bytes are NOT executed as code, they contain string data
    push 0x6f6c6c65     ; 'hello'
    sub al,0x20         ; ', '
    ja  short $+0x6f+2  ; 'wo'
    jb  short $+0x6c+2  ; 'rl'
    db 'd!'
```

To compile I did use `nasm -f elf *.asm; ld -m elf_i386 -s -o demo *.o` (ignore warnings), to backwards decompile and check how the actual machine code is forming instructions you can apply `objdump -M intel -d demo`.

(the code above and `objdump` works also on online site: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_assembly_online.php if you want to test it out)

Answer (score 0):

The string is never executed, because you're issuing a `exit_program` system call prior to reaching that point.

This is what normal code looks like:

```
asm
asm
more asm
call subroutine   ->> will branch to subroutine
        subroutine:  asm
                     more asm
                     ret   ->> executing will return to point after call.
xor eax,eax          <<-- first instruction after the ret
ret                  <<-- return to caller.
```

Here's the annotated version of the `code` subroutine.

```
code:
pop ecx        ;get 'hello world'
mov bl,1       ;write to stdout
mov dl,13      ;length is 14
mov al,4       ;syscall write
int 0x80       ;perform the write
dec bl         ;set exit code to 0 {success}
mov al,1       ;syscall exit
int 0x80       ;exit the program
;the executing does not return here!
string: 
call code 
db 'hello, world!'
```

A better way to do this is to code the last part as follows:

```
.code
hello: db 'hello, world!'

.text
move ecx,hello
mov edx,13
call print         //returns as normal
call exit_program  //will not return

print: mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
int 0x80
ret

exit_program: 
xor ebx,ebx
mov eax,1
int 0x80
```

This has the following benefits:

- It has fewer instructions;
- It does not cause slowness by having unmatched calls/returns
- It does not mess with byte registers
- It is straightforward and easy to understand.
- You can reuse the `print` and `exit_program` subroutines in other parts of the program.

Comment: JFYI: I **guess**, that the original code from question is shell-exploit-code, thus it is including data inside code, using only relative addressing and being "PIC", and avoiding zero byte in resulting machine code (yours `mov edx,13` will contain zeroes after compilation, which makes in not suitable as payload string), so that's very likely the reason why that code is written in such "obfuscated" way.